# Вытянуть энный элемент из объекта?

Tags: javascript

```
var names = {
  name:"Ivan",
  last:"Petrov",
  phone: {
    home: 123456,
    work: 236589
  }
};
```

У меня есть объекты, которые не всегда построены по одной схеме и 3е поле не всегда будет "phone". Возможно ли по ангиологии с массивами извлечь 3й элемент **names[2]**(его имя и свойство) или нужно использовать дополнительно underscore напр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
var obj = names,
    result = false,
    i = 0;
for (var propertyName in obj)
  if (++i == 3) {
    result = { name: propertyName, value: obj[propertyName] };
    break;
  }
console.log(result);
// { name: [имя свойства], value: [значение свойства] } или false, если свойств < 2
```

Кстати, хромушка имеет обыкновение автоматом сортировать объекты по имени свойства, так что я бы пересмотрел подход.

Comment: спасибо за совет, не знал. 
Но код работает на сервере Node.js

Comment: Не забудьте: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FhasOwnProperty